# How to get user feedback/bug reports on a Chrome Extension through itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have created a simple Chrome Extension, but it's not easy for the users to contact me, beyond using the `mailto` function. I also don't have access to a server with which I can send AJAX calls to. Worst case scenario, I'll have the extension create a PasteBin, [via its API](http://pastebin.com/api) of the error string and use `mailto` to email that to me, but that's not quite secure *or* elegant.

Is there a way I can create some sort of 'submit bug' function, easily within jQuery or HTML? Something like `Chrome.SendFeedback()` or `Chrome.SubmitErrorLog()` which gets sent directly to me, somehow?

Comment: The Chrome web store has a feedback tab now. Also, I linked a website to my extension on its page in the Chrome Store. My website has a feedback form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest and quickest way to get feedback from users is going to be to embed a google doc form in an iframe in a page. You can insert it where you would have built a custom form to submit to an API.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzgaUOW6GIs

http://www.google.com/google-d-s/forms/

Comment: I'm new to web development, but I thought iFrames were something frowned upon? This seems like a very good idea though.

Comment: iFrames are great for including content from other sites. That's what iFrames were built for in the first place so in this case it's a good move. Using iFrames for your own content means there is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: Okay, great. Now I just need to figure out how to fill the docs with some template information and I'll be set.