# Integration : Chrome web store and slack

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, slack

I was searching for a way to get some information  from chrome webstore (I have couple of extensions there) specifically feedbacks from users and user count. And I would like to do something with that data.
I searched about chrome [web store API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/api_index)
but couldn't find anything. 
found [launchkit](https://launchkit.io/reviews/) which does same thing, but for appStore

I am thinking there is no straight way to do it, but if anyone has done it or got some idea about it please share it along,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A simple google tells me there are already some possible helpful answers:

- Get user feedbacks
  [How to get user feedback/bug reports on a Chrome Extension through itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394696/how-to-get-user-feedback-bug-reports-on-a-chrome-extension-through-itself)
- Get user count
  [API call for user count in Chrome Web Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005026/api-call-for-user-count-in-chrome-web-store)

Comment: I specifically need the user feed backs, google docs are another way of doing it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can find out is [*chromebeat*](https://www.chromebeat.com/) and [*my extensions*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/my-extensions/igejgfmbjjjjplnnlgnbejpkpdajkblm) I would have to figure out how this works without an existing API and write my own after that I guess.